# Can ping and trace sites but can't view on browser?

Tags: windows-7, internet, browser, dns, internet-connection

I am having issues on certain sites (not all just a few). I can ping and trace sites just fine but for some reason the sites won't load in the browser. They're just stuck at "connected to example.com" in the browser's status bar. Any ideas what is causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for all your suggestions, apparently all I ever need is `ipconfig /flushdns`

Answer (score 0):

You can also test web connectivity using curl, e.g.

```
curl -I https://www.staminus.net
```

This may give you a clue as to why your requests are failing.  You can also watch tcpdump to see what is happening to your traffic when you try to connect to these sites:

```
tcpdump -ni any port 80 and port 443
```

This would give you some clues as to why your requests are failing.

Comment: Sorry but I only have Windows 7 and XP PCs

Comment: http://www.winpcap.org/windump/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely an MTU issue.  Try setting a smaller MTU and see if it solves the problem (1450 should do you).  [Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-do-i-change-the-mtu-setting-in-windows-7/ec01f5d0-7082-4a9d-97b5-1d1dccb121d2) is a link to do this on Windows 7 which says

```
Open a command line window as an Administrator (ie. right click on All Programs > Accessories > Command Prompt and select Run as administrator) ...
Type the command netsh and wait for prompt
Type the command interface and wait for prompt
Type the command ipv4 and wait for prompt
Type the command set subinterface "Local Area Connection" mtu=xxxx store=persistent
```

Answer (score 0):

Davidgo is right this is a most likely a MTU issue ; either your local machine has wrong MTU settings or there is a mismatch in MTUs in your connection to the internet meaning one of the network devices is not broadcasting on the same MTU; inquire with your ISP for the correct MTU settings(it varies according to country,standards and the ISP's infra) then make sure all the devices in your local network are using the the same MTU as provided by the ISP

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me, Is calling the ISP and asking them to give me a different IP.
It seems that the site I was working on, had some filtering system in place That identified my usage as irregular.

I could still ping the site and perform tracert, but I couldn't access it with Any browser
since the IP I was using was blocked.

Hope it helps somebody